# Jmeter how do I generate multiple HTTP request body in one session?

Tags: groovy, jmeter

Here is my use case: I had a JSR223 post processor in place to store "account ID" that qualifies the condition into an array. And then I'll need to construct http request body using the accountId in the array one at a time to test the API. My question is that:
With the code right below,  there was only one request body constructed with the last accountId in the array.. However I needed to generate multiple HTTP request bodies from the loop so that I could hit the api with every each accountId in the array. Is the simple controller able to accomplish this? If so, what shall I do? Thanks!

```
def accountIds = []

for (int i=0; i < territoryTableDataList.size(); i++) {
    if (territoryTableDataList[i].change == "DROPPED") {
        accountIds.add(territoryTableDataList[i].id)
    }
}
for (int j=0; j < accountIds.size(); j++) {
    vars.put("accountId", accountIds[j])
    log.info("*******************The account ID is: " + accountIds[j])
}




HTTP Request Body:
{
  "globalRequestId": "auto-perftest-00",
  "challengeReasons": [
    "other__c"
  ],
  "feedbackRemoveAccountRequests": [
    {
      "requestId": "auto-perftest-001",
      "accountId": "${accountId}"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Seems your api accepting multiple objects with account id. I think you could build request with multiple accounts and call api once.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int j=0; j < accountIds.size(); j++) {
    vars.put("accountId", accountIds[j])
    //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

here you're **overwriting** the `accountId` JMeter Variable with the new value of `accountIds[j]` each iteration of the loop so it always contains the last value.

You need to replace this line with something like:

```
vars.put("accountId_" + (j+1),  accountIds[j])
```

This way you will get the following [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) generated:

```
accountId_1=foo
accountId_2=bar
accountId_3=baz
etc.
```

And these variables can be iterated using [ForEach Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller):

[image]

Demo:
[image]

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)